# What is the bug I am not finding in this code for curzon numbers?

Tags: python, debugging

This is the description of the given problem:

*If 1 plus 2 elevated to num is exactly divisible by 1 plus 2 multiplied by num, then num is a Curzon number.
Given a non-negative integer num, implement a function that returns True if num is a Curzon number, or False otherwise.*

The code I wrote was:

```
def is_curzon(num):
    curr = 0
    mult_add = 2 * num + 1
    while curr <= num:
        if (2**curr + 1) % mult_add == 0:
            return True
        curr += 1
    return False
```

It's not passing the test for when `is_curzon(120)` where the answer is supposed to be `False` but I'm getting `True`.

The obvious answer would be the following and it gives the correct answer for `is_curzon(120)`:

```
def is_curzon(num):
    return not (2**num + 1) % (2*num + 1)
```

But I wanted to lessen the amount of time the program has to run to solve this problem. If `num` is a very big number, I don't want to overwhelm the program.

Could you help me on how I can fix this bug?

Comment: The call `is_curzon(120)` returns True when curr reaches the number 12.

Comment: What made you think that your first version, which involves a loop, would lessen the time taken in comparison to the second version, which is one mathematical expression?

Comment: ohh gotcha. tysm!

Comment: It seems you were looking for an early exit on the first version, but issue is mod(2**num +1, mult_add)` has no relation to `mod(2**curr +1, mult_add)` for 0 <= curr < num.,

Answer (score 0):

```
   return not (2**num + 1) % (2*num + 1)
```

is a statement, which takes less time than a loop, that has to run over and over again:

```
while curr <= num:
    curr+=1
```

has to repeat "num" +1 times because the condition gets false when "curr" gets bigger than num.
(This is a shortened version, in your code `if (2**curr + 1) % mult_add == 0` gets checked first, and returns True if that is the case, else it increases curr by +=1)

if you still want to find the problem in your code, first try to solve it by tracing back what is happening, you can trace it yourself or maybe try to run your code through : http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display and see what happens.